# How to get the HFile from sqoop after bulk hbase import?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I use sqoop to do bulk hbase import. I use this option from sqoop: `--hbase-bulkload`. Sqoop will generate HFiles and import the hfiles to my hbase. I can verify the data is there and from sqoop log, it try to load hfile from

```
INFO mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Trying to load hfile=hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/sqoop/data/u/2ce542f59b56466d988e49f7a7e512b7 first=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xDE1\xF8 last=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xEB:L
```

However, after the job is done. I try to see the files and it is not there anymore. I am using this hadoop command to view files:

```
hadoop fs -ls /tmp/sqoop/data
```

Is the HFile stored somewhere else? Or there is an option to keep it after import job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done importing data into hbase from oracle using sqoop itself.After that importing process has completed,the file is stored in hdfs file system

```
/home/USERNAME/FILENAME(TABLENAME)
```

I think your Hfile also be stored with the same concept so better once check it there

Comment: I checked and it is not there.

Comment: Okay,then have you checked in the whole hdfs file system?
To do so you can use the below link

  http://localhost:50070